# Python Selenium sending keys to a textfield

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, screen-scraping

Im writing a google forms submitter and I'm having problems with the textfield-type questions.
Basically I am using:

```
textfield = question.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")
```

to find the textfield and then the problems start coming in. The type of "textfield" is:`<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="1b49148e-2a24-4efb-b3a5-e84be92223ae", element="3b437c8b-8d05-4410-8047-bcac9ea81f0f")>`
and when I want to call `.send_keys(string)` on it it says that `Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`
So basically it says that the element returned is a list (noenetheless that type() returns a firefoxwebdriver element type).
So if I try to go with `textfield[0] or textfield[1] etc...` it of course throws an error that a FirefoxWebDriver is not subscribable.


What the frick?

Here's the block of code:

```
buttons = question.find_elements_by_class_name("appsMaterialWizToggleRadiogroupRadioButtonContainer")
buttons2 = question.find_elements_by_class_name("quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxInnerBox")
try:
    textfield = question.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")
except:
    print("not found")
    textfield = []
    pass
```

And then below to send keys into it:

```
if len(buttons) == 0 and len(buttons2) == 0:
    print(textfield)    
    textfield.send_keys("lol spam")
```

Comment: Hello Marsin, could you provide a smaller code snippet, including the page that you want to submit to? Cumbersome, I know, but currently it's not possible to debug your question.
Also, are you using an IDE, like VSCode or PyCharm? That'll allow you to introspect your objects at break points through their respective debuggers.

Comment: Hi! I updated the original post.

Comment: Sorry to start giving pointers to debug the thing: it should work if you move the `if len(buttons) ...` into the `try: ...` part. Have it print out what you want and you should be golden. The only thing I am seeing is that it's possible to run into the error you described, because of the broad `except` clause.

Comment: if `find_element_by_class_name` fails, you print out 'not found` and then assign an empty list to `textfield`. Then subsequently you use `textfield`, which now *may* be an empty list (strongly suggested, however, by the exception you are getting),  to execute a call to `send_keys`. Any chance that the message 'not found' printed out prior to the exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    textfield = question.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")
except:
    print("not found")
    textfield = []
    pass
```

The problem lies within this snippet. If `textfield`, or to be more specific the `class_name quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput` can't be found, Python continues to evaluate the `except` block. Within there you stated `textfield = []` - that's the reason for your problems:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute
> 'send_keys' So basically it says that the element returned is a list
> (noenetheless that type() returns a firefoxwebdriver element type). So
> if I try to go with textfield[0] or textfield[1] etc... it of course
> throws an error that a FirefoxWebDriver is not subscribable.

- You can't send `send_keys` to a list.
- List is empty, hence a `textfield[0]` should throw `IndexError`.

---

A solution to this problem is to find the proper `class_name`. *Without a HTML code we can't help you to do that.*